Cómo mejorar un procedimiento en MYSQL, considero que es lento, quiero para mejorarlo
realice un procedimiento e hice pruebas con 320 registros y considero que es tardado en terminar, les comparto el código:
BEGIN
DECLARE @id INT;
DECLARE @proveedor, @activo VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @valorcompra, @valorventa, @cantidad DECIMAL(30, 5);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE @ventas CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM Ventas;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN @ventas;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM @ventas INTO @id, @proveedor, @activo, @valorcompra, @valorventa, @cantidad;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF (SELECT Count(Proveedor) FROM Cartera WHERE Proveedor = @proveedor and Activo = @activo) = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO Cartera (Proveedor, Activo) VALUES (@proveedor, @activo);
        UPDATE Cartera SET USDTc = @valorcompra * @cantidad, USDTv = @valorventa * @cantidad, Ganancias = USDTv - USDTc, Porcentaje = Ganancias / USDTc * 100 WHERE Proveedor = @proveedor and Activo = @activo;
    ELSE
        UPDATE Cartera SET USDTc = USDTc + @valorcompra * @cantidad, USDTv = USDTv + @valorventa * @cantidad, Ganancias = USDTv - USDTc, Porcentaje = Ganancias / USDTc * 100 WHERE Proveedor = @proveedor and Activo = @activo;
    END IF;
    
END LOOP;
CLOSE @ventas;

END

El procedimiento lo que hace es leer una tabla de las operaciones de ventas, en esta tabla se enlistan todas las operaciones que se han realizado, la tabla de ventas puede contener varias operaciones de un mismo activo, por lo que el activo puede repetirse, la idea es alimentar otra tabla para hacer un resumen de las ventas donde ya no hay activos repetidos, es por eso que realizo operaciones algebraicas.


Para que se entienda el código adicione '@' al campo.


Algo extraño, no puedo hacer un INSERT con toda la información que deseo, cuando el activo no existe, tengo que hacerlo en 2 pasos, un INSERT del activo después un UPDATE de la información.


¿Lento? Por lo menos debería decir cuanto se demora y las características del hardware donde probaste.

Es lo que tienen los cursores, ¿ha probado con un UPDATE JOIN? En MySQL las operaciones en bloque son mucho más rápidas que registro a registro. Si necesitas ayuda con esto, pásanos la estructura de la tabla con unos datos de muestra con el resultado que esperas

Diga cuanto es "lento" y por que hay tantas redundancias? Hay un IF que hace un count, para luego hacer INSERT, y luego UPDATE en ambas ocasiones. No sería mejor manejar un ON DUPLICATE KEY ... UPDATE ??

Le llamo lento, porque 320 registros los ejecuta en mas de 10 segundos, primeramente estoy migrando la implementación de Microsoft Access a MYSQL, los equipos son laptop i5, en Access la ejecución es en milisegundos (casi instantáneo) y en MYSQL-Server lo hace en 10 segundos.

Hago un IF con un count para identificar si la consulta WHERE esta vacía, si esta vacía es porque no tengo ese Activo y voy a INSERT el nuevo elemento, pero por una extraña razón (no encontré el porque) si pongo la instrucción INSERT con todos los datos de la fila marca un error de conversión y es por eso que lo hago en 2 etapas, primero INSERT los elementos VARCHAR y después UPDATE los elementos DECIMAL

Bueno, pues amplia la publicación, menciona como lo estás haciendo en Access, y que error de conversión te está dando, por que el problema acá, son los cursores, y las redundancias en la consulta. Realmente no tiene sentido hacer un INSERT y de inmediato un UPDATE a la misma fila.

será conveniente que haga una nueva pregunta y amplié la información tal como me indican?

Cuál es el problema de editar esta?

Prueba así, verás que hace los cálculos de forma mucho más eficiente. En primer lugar, inserto los datos faltantes, después calculo los totales y actualizo la tabla Cartera, dejando para el final las Ganancias y Porcentaje:
INSERT INTO Cartera (Proveedor, Activo)
SELECT DISTINCT Proveedor,Activo
  FROM Ventas
  LEFT JOIN Cartera USING(Proveedor,Activo)
  WHERE Cartera.Proveedor IS NULL;

UPDATE Cartera JOIN (
    SELECT Proveedor,Activo,
      SUM(Valorcompra*Cantidad) USDTc,
      SUM(Valorventa*Cantidad) USDTv
      FROM Ventas
      GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c1 USING(Proveedor,Activo)
  SET Cartera.USDTc=c1.USDTc,
  Cartera.USDTv=c1.USDTv;

UPDATE Cartera set 
  Ganancias = USDTv - USDTc, 
  Porcentaje = Ganancias / USDTc * 100;

El dataset de muestra del que he partido es:
CREATE TABLE `Ventas` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Proveedor` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Activo` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Valorcompra` DECIMAL(30, 5) NOT NULL,
  `Valorventa` DECIMAL(30, 5) NOT NULL,
  `Cantidad` DECIMAL(30, 5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Cartera` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Proveedor` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Activo` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `USDTc` DECIMAL(30, 5) DEFAULT 0,
  `USDTv` DECIMAL(30, 5) DEFAULT 0,
  `Ganancias` DECIMAL(30, 5) DEFAULT 0,
  `Porcentaje` DECIMAL(30, 5) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Proveedor_Activo` (`Proveedor`, `Activo`)
);

-- Script de inserción para la tabla Ventas
INSERT INTO Ventas (id, proveedor, activo, valorcompra, valorventa, cantidad) VALUES
(1, 'Hampton Inc', 'sort', 30.18, 24.63, 5.42),
(2, 'Mendoza-King', 'tell', 67.1, 50.94, 4.59),
(3, 'Garcia PLC', 'lead', 13.13, 43.89, 2.51),
(4, 'Greene Inc', 'industry', 99.36, 38.5, 5.41),
(5, 'Nash LLC', 'near', 45.3, 49.92, 8.74),
(6, 'Rodriguez-Knight', 'need', 97.05, 106.37, 9.21),
(7, 'Harvey-Bowman', 'simply', 99.87, 114.41, 8.16),
(8, 'Wilson-Pena', 'local', 25.18, 47.32, 5.13),
(9, 'Bell, Anderson and Merritt', 'far', 71.37, 42.92, 5.63),
(10, 'Ryan LLC', 'road', 66.56, 73.88, 4.33);


Gracias, no me funcionó, porque copie el ejemplo tal cual y claro funciona al 100, sin embargo en mi tabla ventas si tengo duplicados, a tu ejemplo duplique el registro "1" y cuando ejecuto el procedimiento me manda un error

0 12 19:14:03 call Pruebas.new_procedure() Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'Hampton Inc-sort' for key 'Cartera.Proveedor_Activo' 0.016 sec

Ya lo resolví, en el INSERT le adicione GROUP BY para quitar los duplicados, Gracias

Mejor usa DISTINCT que es más eficiente. ¿Qué tal va ahora de velocidad? Recuerda validar y votar y Gana +2 de reputación

Ya implemente DISTINCT, me gusto mas GROUP BY, repetí varias veces el proceso y el promedio es 0.225 segundos vs 0.135 segundos. Tengo otro proceso que aun no migro del Microsoft ACCSESS al MYSQL y es costear el inventario usando ultimas entradas primeras salidas, en un rato voy a iniciar, sin embargo tengo 1 semana que me inicie en el MYSQL y me cuesta trabajo entender el lenguaje, me recomiendas si es necesario formular otra pregunta o consultarte en forma directa?

¿Hemos mejorado de 10 segundos a 0.2? Mejor pon otra pregunta, es bueno separarlas por conceptos. Deja aquí el enlace y así me entero cuando la publiques. No te olvides de aportar el dataset con algún dato de muestra
